# av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer when streaming to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to stream to an RTMP server using a Python subprocess with FFmpeg. When I wanted to stream it to localhost, everything worked fine. But when I tried to stream it to my designated RMTP server using nginx, now and then, this error will crash the program:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe    
Error writing trailer of rtmp://.../live: Broken pipe
```

I checked the connection to the server it was fine. Here are my settings for my RTMP server using nginx:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for FFmpeg code to stream:

```
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-re',
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', 'pipe:',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'medium',
           '-vsync','vfr',
           '-f', 'flv',
           '-flvflags', 'no_duration_filesize',
           rtmp_url]

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with how the RTMP server is setup and its settings, but I provide the ffmpeg code just in case.

Thank you in advance.